# What does this over mean; looked over at?

Tags: prepositions

> Harry looked ***over*** at the Slytherin table and saw a horrible ghost sitting there, with blank staring eyes, a gaunt face, and robes stained with silver blood. He was right next to Malfoy who, Harry was pleased to see, didn't look too pleased with the seating ar-rangements.
>
> --Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

*Over* seems to mean across in the context. Does it mean Harry looked across/over students at the Slytherin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Over* in contexts like this—*over there*, *over to*, *over at*, combined with another locative and without an object of its own—usually implies a shift of focus: farther away and/or in a different direction.

> Here’s where we are, on Locust Street ... and over *here*’s the museum we’re trying to get to.
>
> Look over there!
>
> Could you run over to the stockroom and get us a case of printer paper?